# Send keys to no element in particular

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

The way I know of sending keys using the WebDriver Python bindings is as follows:

```
element.send_keys(value)
```

How can I send a key (specifically the Escape key) to no element in particular, just to the window in general?

Comment: You can send the keys to the body of the html page. Or do you mean you want to send keys to the browser itself, and not to something rendered on the page?

Comment: "specifically the Escape key" Are you attempting to dismiss/close a pop-up dialog perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I'm attempting to close a dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How do I handle pop up windows?](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_How_do_I_handle_pop_up_windows?)

> WebDriver offers the ability to cope with multiple windows. This is
>   done by using the "WebDriver.switchTo().window()" method to switch to
>   a window with a known name. If the name is not known, you can use
>   "WebDriver.getWindowHandles()" to obtain a list of known windows. You
>   may pass the handle to "switchTo().window()".

Comment: This does not answer the question "Send keys to no element in particular".

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `element` to the body of the HTML document:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body")
element.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to explain what you are adding to the accepted answer? When adding an answer to a question this old that has an accepted answer, a simple one-liner is likely to be considered inadequate.

Comment: I added an example. Even though there is an accepted answer (and the asker obviously is happy with it), I think this answers the original post more directly.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for adding this answer!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to send keys to the window without specifying any particular element in Selenium is with the [ActionChains](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html).

In Python, it looks like this:

```python
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

value = "Randomblue"

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(value)
actions.perform()
```